# How can I remove duplicate strings from an array of strings but only if they start with the same 5 characters in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, methods, duplicates

I have a nodelist:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list > a')
```

Every "a" contains a string

In the example the list is like that:

```
<ul>
<a href="#"><li>Lorem Ipsum dolor</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sit Amet Bla bla</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sit Ahhh ppppp</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Loret loops stuff</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>....</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>...</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>.... and so on</li></a>
</ul>
```

I need to remove for example the the third element because it starts with the same 5 characters of the second element even though they end differently.

Everytime I encounter a new element I need to check if there's another element in the same list starting with the same 5 characters and remove it.

Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just loop over the elements and use a `Set` to collect the prefixes:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.list > a');
const set = new Set();

for (const element of list) {
  const prefix = element.innerText.slice(0, 5);
  
  if (set.has(prefix)) {
    element.remove();
  } else {
    set.add(prefix);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<a href="#"><li>Lorem Ipsum dolor</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sit Amet Bla bla</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Sit Ahhh ppppp</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>Loret loops stuff</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>....</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>...</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>.... and so on</li></a>
</ul>
```